# Windows 8 - How to create a shortcut that opens several programs

Tags: windows, windows-8, automation

I want to make a shortcut which opens sublime text, chrome and 2 git bash consoles and types some commands in it, and resizes the windows.

Is it possible to do it ?

PS: I tried .bat but when i try to open git bash it opens it in terminal (on current terminal) so it can't go on

Comment: That the get bash is opened in the terminal does not mean the solution for the .bat file doesn't work.

Comment: so how can I open it as an external app ?

Comment: Look into batch + `Start.exe`

Answer (score 1):

You can create a shortcut on the desktop to a bat file:

- Right-click an open area on the desktop, point to **New**, and then click
  **Shortcut**.
- Click **Browse**.
- Locate the bat file to which you want to create a shortcut,
  bat file, click **Open**, and then click **Next**.
- Type a name for the shortcut. If a Finish button appears at the
  bottom of the dialog box, click it. If a Next button appears at the
  bottom of the dialog box, click it, click the icon you want to use
  for the shortcut, and then click **Finish**.

Contents of the bat file:

```
1. @echo off
2. start "C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\change.log"
3. start chrome.exe
4. "C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login -i
```

*1st row: Switch off showing running process.*

*2nd row: Start program by path with a parameter (In this case Notepad++ opened own change.log file. The path is required, otherwise the file will not open).*

*3rd row: Run program without parameters.*

*4th row: Run program with parameters.*

> ```
> I tried .bat but when i try to open git bash it opens it in terminal
> (on current terminal) so it can't go on
> ```

Look there: https://stackoverflow.com/q/20837178/3139109

Answer (score 1):

Use bat file with content:

For execution file not in PATH environment variable, use:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\bash.exe" --login
```

For execution file in PATH environment variable, use:

```
start bash --login
```